# Strange ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Tags: android

I received a strange out of bounds exception in the Play Store console relating to the [android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html)

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
    at com.example.MyFragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MyFragmentActivity.java:2068)
    at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4163)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat23.java:32)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:316)
    at com.example.MyFragmentActivity.onConnected(MyFragmentActivity.java:2048)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzi(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.zzpx(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzqL(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is my onRequestPermissionsResult implementation

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                }
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Line 2068 is this:

```
if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

I believe it's claiming `grantResults` length is zero which is why the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.  According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html)

> int: The grant results for the corresponding permissions which is
>   either **PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. Never null.**

`grantResults` will not be null, but doesn't say anything about it not containing a value either.  Furthermore it seems like the callback will contain at least one value, either `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED`.  Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[Documentation about permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) says

> If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.

And it seems to be your situation, so you have to check first if the array is not empty:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                }
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Great answer.

Comment: Does anyone know what "request is cancelled" means? Who cancelled it? I don't know of any API to cancel the request, and I don't understand how a user could cancel it when it's clearly a yes or no thing to the user...

Comment: For anyone who wants more context, there's two places in the Activity source where this will be called with empty result.The first is in [dispatchRequestPermissionsResult](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#7454), which explains that the package installer can crash.
The second is in [requestPermissions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#4387) when we're already waiting on permissions. Quite possible to do this by mistake.

Comment: in my case i'm already checking `if (grantResults.length > 0)`, but still getting this error, can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin code for check Permission & Fix this error:
It's better to check size of IntArray with .isNotEmpty()  in Kotlin.

```
 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (requestCode) {
        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()  &&  grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                choosePhotoFromGallary()
            } else  //Permission Denied
                //  toast("Permission must be granted in order to...")
        }
        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE_CAMERA -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePhotoFromCamera()
            } else  //Permission Denied
                //  toast("Permission must be granted in order to ...")
        }
    } // when
} // fun
```